# Waiting for key press after Plink finishes executing remote command

Tags: ssh, cmd, plink

I am using Plink to execute commands on remote computer. 
For example:

```
plink.exe -l login -pw password net stop spooler
```

Is it possible to do that after executing this command, Plink window will wait for my reaction (for example pressing button on keyboard)?

Comment: Your Plink command-line misses hostname, it cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Plink from a batch file (e.g. `execute_command.bat`) and add [`pause` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pause):

```
@echo off
plink.exe -l login -pw password hostname net stop spooler
pause
```

Or you can do the same using `cmd.exe`, without using a separate batch file:

```
cmd.exe /C plink.exe -l login -pw password hostname net stop spooler & pause
```

---

Or you can use a server-side `pause`-like command on Plink command-line.

From your use of `net stop`, I assume the server is Windows, so again, you can use `pause`:

```
plink.exe -l login -pw password hostname "net stop spooler & pause"
```